# Error when joining two tables using linq in mvc4

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my controller, in `select new` what should I use? If I use any class name the it is showing error like name don't find in this model?

Here the controller code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();

        }

        public ActionResult details()
        {

          var myParts = (from p in db.emps
                          join d in db.depts on p.Eid equals d.Eid
                          select new
                         { 
                            name  =p.name,
                             address = p.address,
                              number=d.number,
                               sub=d.sub
                                }).ToList();

            return View(myParts);

          }
        }    
    }
```

My index page what should I give in model if I give the class name or table name if I give class name then I have two class the which class i give in above model

here this Index page code:

```
@model  IEnumerable<two2.Models.mass>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = " Deaprtment name ";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Department";
}


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor (model => model.address)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor (model => model.sub)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor (model => model.mark)
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.address)
                       </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sub)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.mark)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

and my view page

in index page it is showing `object not found` 
and in `foreach` statement it is showing error

```
@model two2.Models.mass
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "deatils";
}

@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.name)
    <br /><br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address)

    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.address)
    <br /><br />
    <br /><br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sub)

    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.sub)
    <br /><br />
    <br /><br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.mark)

    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.mark)
    <br /><br />
    <button>Login</button>
}
```

I don't know what should I use such that my be class name or table name and how to display on view

Comment: Please use proper language which can be understandable..

Answer (score 0):

You should use same class name in Action also which is used in View like:

```
public ActionResult details()
{
    var myParts = (from p in db.emps
                  join d in db.depts on p.Eid equals d.Eid
                  select two2.Models.mass
                 { 
                    Eid = p.Eid,
                    name = p.name,
                    address = p.address,
                    number = d.number,
                    mark = d.mark,       // <- you need to pass mark as it is used in View
                    sub = d.sub
                }).ToList();

    return View(myParts);
}
```

If you are using in View:

```
@model  IEnumerable<two2.Models.mass>
```

Class `two2.Models.mass` is one type of ViewModel and it should contain only those fields which are needed in View:

```
namespace two2.Models 
{ 
    public class mass 
    { 
        public int Eid { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public int number { get; set; }
        public string sub { get; set; }
        public int mark { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

Comment: namespace two2.Models
{
    public class mass
    {
        public int Eid { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }

        public int Did { get; set; }
        public int number { get; set; }
        public string sub { get; set; }
        public int mark { get; set; }
        public int Eid { get; set; }

    }
}

Comment: namespace two2.Models
{
    public class mass
    {
        public int Eid { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }

        public int Did { get; set; }
        public int number { get; set; }
        public string sub { get; set; }
        public int mark { get; set; }
        public int Eid { get; set; }

    }
}

Comment: Error 1 The type 'two2.Models.mass' already contains a definition for 'Eid' C:\Users\anand.kumar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\two2\two2\Models\mass.cs 24 20 two2

Comment: can any one send me whole part of code to join the two table in mvc4 and that my simple bcz i am fresher i want to learn

Comment: public class mass
    {
        public int Eid { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }

        public int Did { get; set; }
        public int number { get; set; }
        public string sub { get; set; }
        public int mark { get; set; }
        //public int Eid { get; set; }    in this code Eid is already use so it showing error

Comment: Yes you have used `public int Eid { get; set; } ` 2 times which causes the error.. remove one..

Comment: Also you have not passed `mark` from controller and you are showing it in the  `View`